# Angular 8 - Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular, typescript

Im trying to create my own radio button component with two ways binding, and use it in another component:

my-custom-component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, DoCheck, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-buttons-radio',
  templateUrl: './buttons-radio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./buttons-radio.component.css'],
})

export class ButtonsRadioComponent implements DoCheck {
  @Input() options: ButtonRadioItem[];
  @Input() value;
  @Output() valueChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();

  ngDoCheck() {
    this.valueChange.next(this.value);
  }
}
```

my-custom-component.html:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" ngbRadioGroup name="radioBasic" [(ngModel)]="value">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let v of options">
    <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
      <input ngbButton type="radio" [(value)]="v.value">{{v.key}}
    </label>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

usage in  my-parent-component.html:

```
<app-buttons-radio [options]="sourceButtonsRadio" [(value)]="sourceValue"></app-buttons-radio>
```

Everything works fine: the component is shown as expected, the value of `sourceValue` is changing, but each time when I click on radio button I get an error in the console

[image]

I've already tried to inject changeDetectorRef into my custom component and use `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` method, but still got an error. 
How can I handle this error?

Comment: You should really not use `ngDoCheck`, better would be to use `ngOnChanges`. Also look into using the `OnPush` change detection strategy when creating components

Comment: @poul-kruijt `ngOnChanges` doesn’t catch changes when I click on buttons

Comment: but those buttons are inside the component, so you should make the component handle that change, and not depend on `ngDoCheck`. This hook runs way too many times, and will emit `valueChange` constantly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @poul-kruijt, changed my code according suggestions in comments. correct code:

my-custom-component.ts:

```
...
export class ButtonsRadioComponent implements DoCheck {
  @Input() options: ButtonRadioItem[];
  @Input() value;
  @Output() valueChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();

  ngDoCheck() {
    this.valueChange.next(this.value);
  }
}
```

my-custom-component.html:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle"
     ngbRadioGroup name="radioBasic" [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="valueChanged($event)">
      ...
</div>
```

usage in my-parent-component.html: